# cygwin screen PTY error

Tags: cygwin, gnu-screen

After recent Cygwin update, I get the following error while starting screen
No more PTYs 
Sorry, could not find a PTY
[screen is terminating]

What does this error mean? How to solve this?
I searched on google, ppl are suggesting to chmod 666 on /dev/ptmx and /dev/pty* files. I changed them 
$ ls -l /dev/ptmx
crw-rw-rw- 1 satram Domain Users 5, 2 Jun  5 13:40 /dev/ptmx
It doesn't help solve the problem. Does anyone why this error happens and how to solve it?

Comment: I don't know if you ever solved this, but if not, I suggest posting to the Cygwin mailing list (cygwin@cygwin.com).  The Cygwin screen cognoscenti are there.